# How to use the default email client to send an email with an attachment from Java?

Tags: java, email, attachment

I have a Java program which generates a PDF file.  I want the user to click a button to open the default email client ready to send the PDF as an attachment.  The two standard ways of opening the default email client have problems:

1. Java 6 doesn't seem to allow for attachments in the generated message
2. JDIC has a bug which prevents Outlook 2007 from sending the message correctly: http://jdic.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=160

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[JDIC](http://java.net/projects/jdic/) provides some functionality to do this.  Although much of JDIC was absorbed into `java.awt.Desktop` in Java 6, it didn't include the email composition bits.  Unfortunately the JDIC binaries disappeared with the [transition of java.net to the Kenai platform](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/kenai-migration-complete-documents-files-are-imported); I uploaded the most recent versions I could find to the project [JIRA](http://java.net/jira/browse/JDIC-545).

JDIC doesn't play well in OSGi, so I recently extracted the relevant MAPI bits into a bundle called [jmapi](http://github.com/briandealwis/jmapi).

(I posted this answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564147/how-to-open-an-email-client-and-automatically-attach-file-in-java/5464318#5464318) too.)

Answer (score 1):

Did [javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html) go away?  That's sort of the canonical way to set up an attachment.

#### Update

Okay, so if I've got this straight, you want to know how to let your application use an unspecified email client on an unspecified operating system to send a multipart MIME email containing an undefined attachment but not by constructing the MIME message yourself?

... well, okay, I guess you mentioned Outlook so it must be Windows.  But still.

Comment: This is a SWT desktop application so the user will likely have an email client on the desktop and will not want to configure my app for sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you'd like to use the default e-mail client, rather than sent it from Java using the e-mail client (JavaMail)?

Can you provide more details as to the kind of application you're trying to write? I take it this is a client GUI application (Swing/SWT/AWT), but beyond that, I think we're going to need more details.

Comment: I'd say that the app can export a file over email, and the user would like to use his favorite email client to do that.