# How to open an email client and automatically attach file in java

Tags: java, mailto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Start Mail-Client with Attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029579/java-start-mail-client-with-attachment)

I need to create a java code that will open an email client (Outlook, outlook express , etc) and automatically attach a file in it. I tried using mailto but it only opens the mail client and do not attach the file. Help please.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JDIC](http://java.net/projects/jdic/) provides some functionality to do this.  Although much of JDIC was absorbed into `java.awt.Desktop` in Java 6, it didn't include the email composition bits.  Unfortunately the JDIC binaries disappeared with the [transition of java.net to the Kenai platform](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/kenai-migration-complete-documents-files-are-imported); I uploaded the most recent versions I could find to the project [JIRA](http://java.net/jira/browse/JDIC-545).

JDIC doesn't play well in OSGi, so I recently extracted the relevant MAPI bits into a bundle called [jmapi](http://github.com/briandealwis/jmapi).

Comment: I tried JDIC, however getting the following error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.jdic.desktop.internal.impl.ServiceManagerStub_unix`  need help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on particular email clients, but `&attachment` parameter should work for at least some versions of Outlook.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Doesn't work with Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a client application you can take a look at the [java.awt.Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail%28java.net.URI%29)
class.

*From the javadoc...*

> Launches the mail composing window of the user default mail client, filling the message fields specified by a mailto: URI.
>
> A mailto: URI can specify message fields including "to", "cc", "subject", "body", etc. See The mailto URL scheme (RFC 2368) for the mailto: URI specification details.

This doesn't allow you to attach a file, but it will open up the user's mail client.

This link may be helpful... [Using the Desktop API in Java SE 6](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/)

Answer (score 0):

I answered a nearly identical question here:

[Start Mail-Client with Attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029579/java-start-mail-client-with-attachment/6093765#6093765)