# Start Mail-Client with Attachment?

Tags: java, email, email-client, jdic

I'm currently searching for a way (in Java) to start the default mail client with defined receiver, subject and body and with a predefined attachment.

Due to the limitations of the RFC the java.awt.Desktop.mail-Method is not working with attachments. The JDIC-project is dead and the JMAPI-project is rather obscure in the building process. (Needs 1.4 Mozilla-Sources) And I have to build it for 64 bit systems myself.

Is there an alternative? I already read the articles here but using the rundl32.dll and such "solutions" aren't something I want to put in production code.

Comment: Define the parameters of the issue. Can the solution be windows only? Does it have to be pure java? Does it have to be bitness agnostic?

Comment: Windows only working solution would be fine too. But it has to work on 32/64 Bit and Windows XP and Windows Vista/7.

Comment: This must be highly platform dependent.

Answer (score 6):

There does not appear to be any OS agnostic method of doing this in Java as not all OSes provide a standard way to launch the default e-mail application with more than the basic fields for a new email.

On Windows, it is possible to use a JNI interface to MAPI, which will provide more control over opening an email in a mail application. As you mentioned, one such library is JMAPI - however, it appears there are many libraries by such a name with similar purposes. I discovered one that is recently maintained and seems fairly straight-forward. It includes a pre-built binary dll and an accompanying Java JNI-based library.

https://github.com/briandealwis/jmapi

With this code, it seems you would only need to construct a message object and call a method to launch it in a mail application:

    import jmapi.*;
    ...

```
    if (JMAPI.isMapiSupported()) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.setSubject("test!");
        msg.setBody("Hello world");

        List<String> toAddresses = new LinkedList<String>();
        toAddresses.add("example@example.com");
        msg.setToAddrs(toAddresses);

        List<String> attachPaths = new LinkedList<String>();
        //Must be absolute paths to file
        attachPaths.add("C:\Users\Documents\file.jpg");
        msg.setAttachments(attachPaths);

        JMAPI.open(msg);
    }
```

---

Another possibility that might work for Windows and Mac (and potentially other OSes) is to generate a ".eml" or ".msg" file with the content and attachments you would like to include already encoded as part of the email. This file could then be launched with the default handler for the respective email file format. However, this is not guaranteed to open the default email handler, nor is the file format going to be compatible with everyone email client.

Comment: This JMapi is exactly the library I mentioned above, so it doesn't work with 64 Bit systems which is a must. And the solution with the eml file is - as you pointed out - not safe. E.g. my computer doesn't have an EML compatible mail client installed.

Comment: +1 for the clean code snipped and -1 for ignoring that the solution should work on a 64-bit system

Comment: I am trying to use in my java web application (Developer environment is: **Ubuntu 12.04**, **Jdk6**). However, I am getting following error.  `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.jdesktop.jdic.desktop.internal.impl.WinAPIWrapper.RegOpenKey(I[BI)[I`

Comment: @vissu Unfortunately this is a Windows only solution as it uses JNI to use Windows native libraries (non JVM).

Answer (score 0):

(as far as I know) That is currently not possible to add a predefined attachment but you can do other things that you mentioned (to start the default mail client with defined receiver, subject and body) using java.awt.Desktop.mail.. I believe that you have already checked [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/). It would be very useful though.

Comment: The question is if there's beside the Desktop-API any reliable way for doing such.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's too late by now, but just in case anybody still finds this problem:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().mail(new URI("mailto:email@example.com?subject=attachment_example&body=see_attached_file&attachment=/path/to/attachment"));
```

should do the trick in a platform-independent way.

Comment: This won't work (i even tested), since mailto doesn't support attachments.

Comment: @ScriptKiddy: you're right - the mailto RFC does not implement the "attachment" extension. But some email clients honor it. For example Evolution for Linux works (at least for me!). Thunderbird does not. Thanks for pointing out!