# How to open default mail client (e.g outlook) with attachment in Java

Tags: java

I want to open a new message, in the system default mail client, and include an attachment, from Java.

I tried `Desktop.mail(URI mailtoURI)` but I do not know how to specify the attachment.

Then, I tried JavaMail. It is working, but I am not able to open the default mail client

How to call the default mail client from within Java, and specify an attachment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start Mail-Client with Attachment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029579/start-mail-client-with-attachment)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. The `Desktop.mail` launches `mailto` handler.

The `mailto` scheme handler only supports to, cc, subject and body.

Since the `mailto` scheme only supports mime type of `text/plain`, it does not support any attachments.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to do this neatly, in a cross-platform way.

See [Start Mail-Client with Attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029579/start-mail-client-with-attachment/6093765#6093765) for an explanation of how to do it in Windows

There is no agreed standard for adding attachments to messages, therefore every mail client handles it differently. This means it is not possible to write a catch-all method to do this for every possible mail client.