# Open default mail box with attachment using jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, email

I am trying to open the default mail box with the pdf attachment, using my jsp button with the following script in jsp

```
<a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com?subject=my report&body=see attachment&attachment="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/report_generate_pdf_ajax_call" class="navLink"><span>Email </span></a>
```

But it is able to open the default mail box with blank email, but not able to get the attachemnt from the url: `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/report_generate_pdf_ajax_call`

I took the help of following link [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045816/to-open-outlook-mail-from-java-program-and-to-attach-file-to-the-mail-from-direc) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955560/how-to-open-default-mail-clientfor-e-g-outlook-with-attachment-in-java)[Link3](http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://forums.devshed.com/beginner-programming-16/using-mailto-attachment-66699.html&grqid=HeTzQRcu&hl=en-IN) but I haven't got success with my result.

Any help regarding in this context will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not add an attachment to a message with the mailto.
mailto: only supports header values or text/plain content.

> There is no provision for it in the mailto: protocol, and it would be
>   a gaping security hole if it were possible. The best idea to send a
>   file is:
>
> 1. Have the user to choose a file
> 2. Upload the file to a server and the server return a random file name after upload
> 3. Build a mailto: link that contains the URL to the uploaded file to the server in the message body

So probably you can use apache commons for this but there will be a place on the server where all the user files will be located that will require cleaning from time to time somehow.

For more info kindly see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233556/using-mailto-to-send-email-with-an-attachment-html-or-jsf)