# Primefaces exported CSV file as file attachment to email in JSF window

Tags: jsf, csv, primefaces, email-attachments

Been searching for this but can't find any answers.

I am currently working on a web app where in I need to attach a csv file which contains the values from p:datatable.

i have an "export to csv" button which uses primefaces exporter and this is working fine.

i also have other button "sendEmail", which opens like a new email message. what i am trying to do is to automatically attach the csv exported file to that new email message window when i click this button. but have no idea how to do this.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Who is sending the mail? The client or the server?

Comment: can already send an email ung java mail api.. however, not able to attach the exported csv file.

Comment: [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029579/start-mail-client-with-attachment), but the very idea in itself is questionable: you're counting on your users to have a mail client configured, not to mention "mailto" is a bit dated

Comment: I already solved this. Thank you